# Add and multiply perplexing numbers

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, complex-numbers

The [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number), also known as "perplex numbers" are similar to the complex numbers.  Instead of `i^2 = -1`, however, we have **`j^2 = 1; j != +/-1`**.  Each number takes the form of `z = x + j*y`.

In one attempt to limit the complexity of this challenge, I will use the symbol `-` to represent negation, as there will not be any subtraction.

Here are some examples for your viewing pleasure:

```
6 * 9 = 54            // real numbers still act normally
5 + -7 = -2
j*1 + j*1 = j*2           // two `j`s added together make a j*2
7 * j*1 = j*7           // multiplication is commutative & associative
j*1 + 2 = 2+j*1           // like oil and water, "combine" to form a split-complex number
j*1 + j*-3 = j*-2          // seems okay so far
j*j*1 = j*-1*j*-1 = 1     // kinda sketchy, but such is its inherent nature
j*j*-1 = j*-1*j*1 = -1  
(2+j*3)+(4+j*7) = 6+j*10  // combine like terms
7 * (2+j*3) = 14+j*21 // distributive property
j * (2+j*3) = (j*2) + (j*j*3) = 3+j*2   // since j^2 = 1, multiplying my j "swaps" the coefficients
(2+j*3)*(4+j*7) = (2*4)+(2*j*7)+(j*3*4)+(j*3*j*7) = 8+j*14+j*12+21 = 29+j*26 // a complete multiplication
```

### Challenge

The goal of this challenge is to evaluate an expression with split-complex numbers.

This is **code-golf,** the fewest bytes wins.

**Input**

Input will be a single line containing only the symbols `+*()-`, the digits `0123456789`, and the letter `j`, with an optional newline.  This string represents an expression, using infix notation and operator precedence (multiplication before addition, with parenthesis grouping).

- The symbol `-` will always represent negation, never subtraction.  **If you so desire, you can replace `-` with either `_` or `~`** for ease of I/O.
- Parenthesis can be nested up to three times to denote grouping: `(1+(1+(1)))`
- The letter `j` will never be directly prefixed with negation, and will always be followed by `*`.
- Parentheses will not be preceded by negation `-(7)`, but instead like `-1*(j*5+2)`
- There will never be implicit operations. All multiplication will be expressed as `(7)*7` instead of `(7)7`, and as `j*5` instead of `j5`.
- No leading zeros.

**Output**

Output will be in the form of `X+j*Y`, where X and Y can be any integer.  If an integer is negative, it should be prefixed with the negation sign.

### Additional Restrictions

Although I am not aware of any language with native support, built-ins that deal with split-complex numbers are forbidden.  Regular complex numbers are fair game.

### Test Cases

Similar to the above examples, but tidied up.  Input on one line and output the line beneath.

```
(2+j*3)+(4+j*7)
6+j*10

(2+j*3)*(4+j*7)
29+j*26

(-5+j*1+j*2+2)*(4+j*7)
9+j*-9

(1+j*-1)*(1+j*1)
0+j*0 // this is why division does not exist.

j*((j*-1)+2)
-1+j*2

(2+(5+-1*(j*1))+2)
9+j*-1
```

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2, 62 bytes

```python
def f(s):b,a=[eval(s)/2.for j in-1,1];print'%d+j*%d'%(a+b,a-b)
```

We simply evaluate the expression `s` with  `j=1` and `j=-1`, and output half their sum and half their difference as the coefficients of `1` and `j`.

This works because both `j=1` and `j=-1` satisfy the defining equation defining equation `j*j==1`. So, the original and simplified expressions must be equal for both these values. The simplified expression is linear, so this gives two linear equations in two unknowns:

```python
x + 1*y  = s(1)  = 2*a
x - 1*y  = s(-1) = 2*b
```

which is solved by `x=a+b, y=a-b`.

Comment: A language with matrix operations could also evaluate the expression with `j=[0 1; 1 0]` and read off coefficients from the top row.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 258

```
class c(complex):__mul__=lambda s,o:c(s.real*o.real+s.imag*o.imag,s.real*o.imag+s.imag*o.real);__add__=lambda s,o:c(sum(map(complex,[s,o])))
import re
r=eval(re.sub("j","c(0,1)",re.sub(r"(-?\d+)",r"c(\1)",raw_input())))
print`int(r.real)`+"+j*"+`int(r.imag)`
```

This is probably not the best approach, but it was the first time that OOP looked like a passable idea in Python for code golf, so why not?

Creates a class `c` that inherits from complex but has a different `mul` operation. The `add` operation is also changed so that it returns an object of type `c` and not `complex`, this behaviour is necessary to prevent the case of `(a + b) * (c + d)` doing complex multiplication instead of this special kind.

The input string is then converted into a string that can be evaluated naturally by python. It does this by changing every number into `c(number)` and then every `j` into `c(0,1)`.

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/KCCNsv) or run a [Test Suite](https://ideone.com/khcGzZ)

Answer (score 1):

### [GAP](http://gap-system.org), 38 bytes

```
j:=X(Integers,"j");f:=t->t mod(j^2-1);
```

First `j` is defined to be an indeterminate, so we can create polynomials in `j`. To get the corresponding perplexing number, we reduce (i.e. take the remainder of polynomial division) by `j^2-1`. This gives a linear (or constant) term, and we can rely on GAP's ability to output polynomials.

Examples:

```
gap> f((2+j*3)+(4+j*7));
10*j+6
gap> f((1+j*-1)*(1+j*1));
0
```

Caveat: 1. This does not take a string as input, but a real term in GAP's language. To fix, I could use `EvalString`. 2. The output is nice and clear, but not exactly as specified: Order is changed, and unnecessary zeroes are suppressed. I think and hope this is still in the spirit of the challenge, otherwise I guess I'd be better off using @xnor's matrix approach.

Comment: Mathematica's `PolynomialMod[#,j^2-1]&` has similar properties. Indeed, if we never multipled more than two perplex numbers together (like the test cases don't), then `Expand@#/.j^2->1` suffices.

Comment: Similarly, `t->t%(j^2-1)` in Pari/GP.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, <s>20</s> 42 bytes

```
f(x,n)==x^(n rem 2);m:=rule('j^n==f('j,n))
```

the preceding solution have a problem if `n<0` in `j^n`
but this it seems more solid, and advise well where there is something wrong, even if the perfection would be return example j^1.2 or j^sqrt(-1) the same expression not evaluate

```
(9) -> f(x,n)==x^(n rem 2);m:=rule('j^n==f('j,n))
         n
   (9)  j  == 'f(j,n)
                    Type: RewriteRule(Integer,Integer,Expression Integer)
(10) -> [m((2+j*3)+(4+j*7)), m((2+j*3)*(4+j*7)), m((-5+j*1+j*2+2)*(4+j*7))]
   (10)  [10j + 6,26j + 29,- 9j + 9]
                                            Type: List Expression Integer
(11) -> [m((1+j*-1)*(1+j*1)), m(j*((j*-1)+2)), m(2+(5+-1*(j*1))+2)]
   (11)  [0,2j - 1,- j + 9]
                                            Type: List Expression Integer
(12) -> [m(j*j*j*j),m(j*j*j),m(j^200)]
   (12)  [1,j,1]
                                            Type: List Expression Integer
(13) -> [m(j^0),m(j^-1),m(j^-2), m(j^-3)]
            1   1
   (13)  [1,-,1,-]
            j   j
                                            Type: List Expression Integer
(14) -> m(j^(3.4))
   There are no library operations named m
      Use HyperDoc Browse or issue
```

if i not follow some law of the question: say me that and i add "not competitive". I mean it as one axiom for simplify formula

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 52 bytes

```
@set/aj=1,a=%1,j=-1,a-=b=(a-(%1))/2
@echo %a%+j*%b%
```

After seeing @xnor's excellent answer nomination I felt compelled to port it.